# What to do next after predicting y?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I've pre-processed the dataset and checked for possible multicollinearity of the independent variables.

The dataset has 6 columns with 31 rows which I used to generate 1/3 as X_test and y_test and remaining is X_train and y_train.

I fit the X_train and y_train to the regressor using sklearn.linear_model LinearRegression function and using the predict function for the X_test which gives me the predicted value for y.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('daily_raw_status.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values # IVs
y = dataset.iloc[:, 6].values # DV

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)

# Fitting MLR to the Training Set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression() # create object
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) # using fit method, fit the multiple regressor to training set

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
Now that I have the y_pred, I can now check the y_pred to the y_test if it's nearly the same.
```

Question is:

What else can I do with y_pred or where should I focus in interpreting the model? and any idea/concepts on how am I able to re-purpose the model for possible real-time dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Further, you can do:

1. [interpret the beta coefficients and intersect](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_interpret_coefficients_from_a_beta_regression)
2. [Find the RMSE or MAE to check the error](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d)
3. if RMSE or MAE is high: outliers treatment or [feature selection (find potential predictors)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

A very typical step in the interpretation of regression models is an ANOVA analysis.  This common type of analysis allows you to evaluate your overall model significance, significance and magnitude of the coefficients, R² and more. See [ANOVA example](https://pythonfordatascience.org/anova-python/) for an example using the 'statsmodels' package. Statsmodels generally offers a lot more tools to interpret and evaluate regression models.

To see if your models is suitable for prediction you might want to check whether the prediction quality is satisfactory for your purpose. This can include

- Finding a suitable metric
- Comparing performance on train and test set
- Checking the range of values

From a practical perspective it is often useful to plot predicted and actual values to get a feeling for your prediction quality.